# What happens when I assign a `ref` value to an `out` argument in C#?

Tags: c#, memory, parameters, unsafe, stackalloc

I am writing an class that retrieves binary data and supports generically converting it into primitive types. It's supposed to be as efficient as possible. Here is what it looks like right now:

```cs
public abstract class MemorySource {
    public abstract Span<byte> ReadBytes(ulong address, int count);

    public unsafe bool TryRead<T>(ulong address, out T result) where T : unmanaged {
        Span<byte> buffer = ReadBytes(address, sizeof(T));
        result = default;
        // If the above line is commented, `result = ref <...>` won't compile, showing CS0177.
        if (!buffer.IsEmpty) {
            result = ref Unsafe.As<byte, T>(ref buffer.GetPinnableReference());
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Since I'm working with large amounts of memory, and my code is going to be performing a lot of small reading operations. I want to minimize the amount of times the memory is copied around.

The `ReadBytes` implementation will either **a)** create a span across a part an already existing array on the heap, or **b)** `stackalloc` a buffer and fill it with data from a remote source (depending on the data I'll be working with). The point is, it will not be allocating anything on the heap by itself.

I want my `TryRead<T>` method to return a typed reference to the span's memory, rather than copy that memory into a new value, and I want to know if that's possible. I've noticed that I can't assign a `ref` value to an `out` argument without initializing it, but I can after, which makes little sense if we assume that I'm assigning a reference.

I guess what I'm asking is, what's really going on in this code? Am I returning a reference to an existing value, or is that value being copied into a new stack-allocated one? And how would the behavior be different with stack-allocated and heap-allocated spans? Would GC know to update the reference of type `T` when moving the data, in case of a heap-allocated span being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primitive types are value types anyway, so you shouldn't worry about allocating on the heap when reading them.

You cannot use `stackalloc` for this code, because you can't (or shouldn't try to) return a pointer to it, as it will be destroyed at the end of the function.

The code you have so far is dangerous, because you are returning a pinnable reference which is not actually pinned.

The reason you are having problems with the `ref` parameter is because in the `else` you are not assigning it at all. You should move the `result = default;` line into the `else` branch.

---

Either way, you are far better off using `MemoryMarshal` for all of this, note that this does not require unsafe code

```
public bool TryRead<T>(ulong address, out T result) where T : unmanaged
{
    ReadOnlySpan<byte> buffer = ReadBytes(address, sizeof(T));
    if (!buffer.IsEmpty)
    {
        result = MemoryMarshal.Read<T>(buffer);
        return true;
    }
    result = default;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hm, yeah, I've just tried debugging this code with a dummy read, and while the span was initialized correctly in `ReadBytes`, the span's contents were all `0xFF`'s outside of it (I believe that's what used to be the method's stack), so it looks like what I'm thinking of isn't possible... Guess I'll have to make `TryRead` abstract too, so that the inheriting classes will be responsible for minimizing the copying operations. Thanks!

Comment: Presumably you are using a `Span` that was allocated on the stack. As mentioned, you can't do that because it will be wiped. It *needs* to be from a `byte[]` array

Comment: I ended up abstracting to `void*` so I wouldn't have to worry about stack-allocated spans' lifetime anymore.

Comment: `void*` is also dangerous, you are letting a pointer go out of control of Garbage Collection. `Span` is there for a reason, it stays within GC control. You could use `Memory` maybe, might be easier to deal with

Comment: Yeah, the idea is that the unsafe code is only really used inside this class, and the workflow code can operate with safe types like `Span` and `Memory`. I think this new implementation works best: https://gist.github.com/TheLeftExit/68be0989ffbc77e43fe9c8a36c1b99ed